# Attach behaviour to namespace calling in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, namespaces, attachedbehaviors

I am very mediocre in Javascript and looking around I was not able to find any information on how to achieve the behaviour I want or if it's even possible.

I have a namespace `form` to access my HTML form:

```
var form = (function(){
    all   = function () $('#myform .entry');
    first = function () $('#myform .entry').first();
})();

form.all.css('color', 'blue');
form.first.css('color', 'red');
```

Desired extra behaviour:

```
form.css('background-color', 'green'); // should be calling $('#myform')
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a namespace, you have an object literal containing functions *(and now you edited it, and added an IIFE, which makes even less sense)*, and the functions have to return something to be able to use it

```
var form = {
    all : function () {
        return $('#myform .entry');
    },
    first : function () {
        return $('#myform .entry').first();
    }
}

form.all().css('color', 'blue');
form.first().css('color', 'red');
```

or if you want to store the collection in an object without looking up in the DOM each time

```
var form = $('#myform');

form.all   = $('#myform .entry');
form.first = $('#myform .entry').first();

form.all.css('color', 'blue');
form.first.css('color', 'red');
```